# bash replace ip with hostname using nslookup on a file

Tags: bash, nslookup

i have a tempfile that outputs this information

```
1.2.3.4 34
1.2.3.5 23
1.2.3.6 22
```

The first columns are ip adresses, and the second one are simultaneos connections to databases, i need to output the first column not as an ip address but as a hostame, and keep the info of the second column

Desired output

```
hostname1 34
hostname2 23
hostname3 22
```

thanks in advance...

Comment: So you want to combine with the data in `/etc/hosts`?

Comment: So u want like sed -i.bak s/1.2.3./hostname/g tempfile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this maybe:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read ip n
do
   # Uncomment following to use /etc/hosts
   # name=$(awk -v ip=$ip '$1 ~ ip{print $2}' /etc/hosts)
   # Uncomment following to use nslookup
   # name=$(nslookup $ip| grep "name ="|sed 's/.*=//')
   # Uncomment following line to use dig (thanks to Charles Duffy)
   # name=$(dig +short -x $ip)
   echo $name $n
done < file
```

Comment: I'd suggest providing an option to use `dig -x +short` -- more likely than `nslookup` to be present on modern systems.

Comment: ...on Linux, there's also the option of `read -r _ name _ < <(getent hosts "$ip")`, which has the advantage of using the system resolver.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you want to achieve, but this will literally get the "desired output"

```
awk 'BEGIN {x = 1} {printf "hostname%s %s\n", x, $2; x += 1}' tempfile
```

Comment: hi, maybe i wasnt too clear on this, but what i needed was to output the hostname of the ip address that i had, the previously answer works exactly as i needed, thanks a lot for taking some time to answer!

Answer (score 0):

How about `logresolve` from `apache2-utils`? It detects what looks like an IP address and replaces it with the resolved hostname:

```
$ cat tempfile
1.2.3.4 34
1.2.3.5 23
1.2.3.6 22

$ cat tempfile | logresolve
hostname1 34
hostname2 23
hostname3 22
```